# Typo3 RealURL: show page id

Tags: typo3, realurl

I want to use RealUrl extension in my typo3 site.
What I want to do:
change the usual url

```
"http://mysite.it/pag/index.php?id=1"
```

into

```
"http://mysite.it/pag/1"
```

(I wanto to hide "index.php?id=")

Is it possible to do it using RealUrl? Can someone help me?  (conf example)
Thank you

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible. Please tell us what you tried already. A start would be to install realurl and clear the caches.

Comment: Another way is to do it with RewriteRule in .htaccess. May this is faster.

Comment: I have tried to install the latest RealUrl and it creates the realurl_autoconf.conf file. But I cannot undestand how to modify the default to obtain url like /pag/number. I don't want a spaeking url I wanto only the page id. Is it realy possible with realUrl. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In this way you probably do not need realurl.

Any url of type `https://mydomain.tld/?{pageid}` will be mapped by TYPO3 core to `index.php?id={pageid}` so you need just a small htaccess rewrite to insert the questionmark.

It is just that links are not generated in this short form. But that could be done by a lastplace replacement (do a stdWrap.replacement on the `PAGE`object):

```
page = PAGE
page {
    10 = ...
    :

    stdWrap.replacement {
        1.search = index.php?id=
        1.replace =
    }
}
```

---

Your request reminds to the core-extension `simulate static`, but that might be obsolete and the pattern differs from your request. It was `https://mydomain.tld/{pagetitle}.{pageid}[.{pagetype}].html`. For the default-pagetype `0` the pagetype does not need to render.

Comment: I have a doubt about RewriteRule.
 I added a rewrite rule like the following  inside the .htaccess in /page directory
 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{1,})/?$  \?$1 

to rewrite i.e. /pag/3  into /pag/?3
but on our site there are url like /pag/21400/?MP=21400-128  (with a query string) and my poor rewrite rule does not work. Have you an example of better rewrite rule?